# How to get files from HttpServletRequest in Java Servlet

Tags: java, servlets

The form in the HTML is like

```
...
<form method="post" action="/foobar">
  <input type="file" name="attachment" />
  <input type="text" name="foo" />
  ... other input fields
</form>
```

And the Servlet will be like

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String attachment = request.getParameter("attachement");
    String foo = request.getParameter("foo");
    // get other parameters from the request
    // and get the attachment file
}
```

And I'm wondering

1. Is there any ways that do not use 3rd-party libraries to get files from a `HttpServletRequest` object?
2. What `request.getParameter("attachement")` returns? Is it the file name or something else?
3. Would the binary input be stored automatically by a web container in file system or just in memory temporarily?

Comment: Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824

Comment: You also might take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831680/httpservletrequest-get-post-data it process JSON data. If your attachment is represented by an URL, you would need to HTTPURLConnection to fetch the data.

Answer (score 2):

before anythging your form action should be "POST" and enctype="multipart/form-data".

that said...for you to get the file you must prepare the request yourself.

you should check:

[Multipart requests/responses java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595173/multipart-requests-responses-java)

Answer (score 0):

add in your form 
enctype="multipart/form-data"

```
<form name="formname" action="servletName" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="attachment" />
  <input type="text" name="foo" />
  ... other input fields
</form>
```

now when you submit the form
on the controller side you can get the picture by

```
String picture = (request.getParameter("attachment")).getBytes();
```

i have assumed the file to be a image , you can pass any file

Comment: Shouldn't you receive the file in a byte array instead of a String. Anyways its not even gonna compile. May be a typo from your end.